# ADLDS userclass ms-DS-UserAccountAutoLocked attribute not visible

Tags: c#, directoryservices, adlds

I've a local installation of an "Active directory lightweight directory service" on a WIN7 machine (which is domain joined).

Controlled by a Policy a user gets locked for about 15mins if there where 5 failed login attempts.
With ADSI-Edit i can see that there is an attribute on the "UserClass" 
named "ms-DS-UserAccountAutoLocked" with an boolean value.

But if i want to read this attribute from this user (via a second admin(!) authenticated binding) it always returns null - like the property does not exist.
If i iterate through all properties this property isnt also shown up.
Only at the ADSI-Edit i can see the property and its value.

Have anyone an idea why i cannot read this property in my code? (C#)

I have tried:

```
var property = adentry.Properties["ms-DS-UserAccountAutoLocked"];
```

and also:

```
var property = adentry.InvokeGet("ms-DS-UserAccountAutoLocked");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property is an calculated one and must be refreshed before!

```
adentry.RefreshCache(new string[] { "ms-DS-UserAccountAutoLocked"});
```

Take a look at another thread of mine (same effect):

[get-all-writeable-properties-of-an-adlds-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627475/get-all-writeable-properties-of-an-adlds-class/26891125#26891125)