# Get all writeable properties of an ADLDS-Class

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, adlds

I'm developing an application which can deal with a MS-ADLDS-Service.
Currently it is possible to create Directory-Entries and assign values to some properties.
Not a realy exciting task until this:

Im my application it's possible (it should be) to configure which properties of a class (for instance: the CN=Person class) should be assigned with values which are evaluated at runtime in my application.

Long story short:
**I want to retrieve all (writeable) properties of a class. Without creating and saving a new CN=Person-Object before.**

Currently i use my schemaBinding to get the Directory-classSchema-Entry of the Person-Class (CN=Person) from where i read some property-values (like "AllowedAttributesEffective", "mayContain", "AllowedAttributes") - i get the most properties by this way - but some Properties are missing! For instance the "telephoneNumber"-Property (attributeSchema: CN=Telephone-Number)

Does anybody know how to get these properties of a class? ADSI-Edit does this: when i create a new object with adsi-edit i can assign values to all possible properties before committing the new entry.

thanks a lot for any hint!

(.net code is welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for my task!

Some of these properties are "calculated" and not persistent at the directoryentry.
So its meant to call the `RefreshCache()` Method and pass the needed property names as an string array.

```
directoryEntry.RefreshCache(new string[] { "allowedAttributesEffective",
                                            "allowedAttributes",
                                            "systemMayContain",
                                            "systemMustContain" });
```

After that call, the properties have values....

```
if (directoryEntry.Properties["systemMayContain"]).Value != null)
   {
    /// Success
   }
```